# Angular UI Calendar / Full Calendar drag event not working (edit) - in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

So I have just added the Angular UI Calendar using Full Calendar to my app. I have gotten it initialized using the example code from the Angular UI Calendar site: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

My issue is that I am unable to 'drag' events. The drag start never occurs. Click event callback works, "editable" config option is set to `true`, and I have searched High and low through the documentation, Google and SO without any luck. I have the following js files loading in what I have confirmed is the correct order: (note* jquery [v.2.2.0] is packaged through the dataTables CDN showing first)

```
 <!-- DataTables/JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/bs-3.3.6/jq-2.2.0,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.11,af-2.1.1,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,b-flash-1.1.2,b-html5-1.1.2,b-print-1.1.2,cr-1.3.1,fc-3.2.1,fh-3.1.1,kt-2.1.1,r-2.0.2,rr-1.1.1,sc-1.4.1,se-1.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.colResize.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Growl -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/bootstrap-growl-master/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Switch -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Pace Loading -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Ion Slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULAR JS -- MAKE SURE CDN ANGULAR FILES VERSIONS MATCH -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular-Datatables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datatables/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular-Sortable -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jQueryUI/sortable.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular-UI-Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/AngularUI/ui.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Moment -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/Moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Full Calendar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.7.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular-UI-Calendar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/AngularUI/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/Controllers/calendarController.js"></script>
```

My calendar is showing, events are populating and I can manipulate the model with successful changes, BUT I cannot drag any events. To be more specific as well, I am not trying to drop outside events, just simply move existing events to different days.

html:
*app is declared on parent page this is an ng-view /// controller is declared through route provider.

```
    <section class="content-header">
  <h1>Calendar</h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li class="active">Calendar</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Calendar</h3>
                    <div class="alert-success calAlert" ng-show="alertMessage != undefined && alertMessage != ''">
                    <h4>{{alertMessage}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

rendered view => pic of calendar rendered:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: added my controller *Identical to example code from Angular UI Calendar site

```
app.controller('CalendarController', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', '$log', '$uibModal', 'uiCalendarConfig', '$compile', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, $log, $uibModal, uiCalendarConfig, $compile, $timeout) {
  var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $scope.changeTo = 'Hungarian';
    /* event source that pulls from google.com */
    $scope.eventSource = {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
    };
    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.events = [
      {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
      {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
      {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];
    /* event source that calls a function on every view switch */
    $scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
      var s = new Date(start).getTime() / 1000;
      var e = new Date(end).getTime() / 1000;
      var m = new Date(start).getMonth();
      var events = [{title: 'Feed Me ' + m,start: s + (50000),end: s + (100000),allDay: false, className: ['customFeed']}];
      callback(events);
    };

    $scope.calEventsExt = {
       color: '#f00',
       textColor: 'yellow',
       events: [
          {type:'party',title: 'Lunch',start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),allDay: false},
          {type:'party',title: 'Lunch 2',start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),allDay: false},
          {type:'party',title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
        ]
    };
    /* alert on eventClick */
    $scope.alertOnEventClick = function( date, jsEvent, view){
        $scope.alertMessage = (date.title + ' was clicked ');
    };
    /* alert on Drop */
     $scope.alertOnDrop = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Dropped to make dayDelta ' + delta);
    };
    /* alert on Resize */
    $scope.alertOnResize = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Resized to make dayDelta ' + delta);
    };
    /* add and removes an event source of choice */
    $scope.addRemoveEventSource = function(sources,source) {
      var canAdd = 0;
      angular.forEach(sources,function(value, key){
        if(sources[key] === source){
          sources.splice(key,1);
          canAdd = 1;
        }
      });
      if(canAdd === 0){
        sources.push(source);
      }
    };
    /* add custom event*/
    $scope.addEvent = function() {
      $scope.events.push({
        title: 'Open Sesame',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        className: ['openSesame']
      });
    };
    /* remove event */
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.events.splice(index,1);
    };
    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function(view,calendar) {
      uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView',view);
    };
    /* Change View */
    $scope.renderCalender = function(calendar) {
      $timeout(function() {
        if(uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]){
          uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
        }
      });
    };
     /* Render Tooltip */
    $scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) {
        element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                      'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
        $compile(element)($scope);
    };
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
      }
    };

    $scope.changeLang = function() {
      if($scope.changeTo === 'Hungarian'){
        $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNames = ["Vasárnap", "Hétfő", "Kedd", "Szerda", "Csütörtök", "Péntek", "Szombat"];
        $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNamesShort = ["Vas", "Hét", "Kedd", "Sze", "Csüt", "Pén", "Szo"];
        $scope.changeTo= 'English';
      } else {
        $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNamesShort = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
        $scope.changeTo = 'Hungarian';
      }
    };
    /* event sources array*/
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventsF];
    $scope.eventSources2 = [$scope.calEventsExt, $scope.eventsF, $scope.events];
}]);
```

EDIT: I have done some more extensive testing and found that drag only fails in chrome browser ... Edge, IE, Firefox, and Opera work as expected, still not sure why ...

Answer (score -2):

I had this same issue, it has to do with your computers touch screen.

Go to chrome://flags and disable 'Enable touch events'

That did the trick for me

Source : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/407

Comment: I have a touch screen computer. Your suggestion breaks touchscreen for my browser on all sites ... ultimately still searching